# How to prove $\ln (2^x+3^x)$ is strictly convex?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I believe (when I look at their graphs) that the following function is strictly convex
$$\ln (2^x+3^x)$$
More generally, I think
$$\ln (a^x+b^x)$$
should be strictly convex as well. Here $a, b>0$, $a\neq b$ and $\ln$ stands for natural logarit.

But I don't know how to prove (or may be disprove it)? Could anyone help me! Thank!

---

**Edit:** According to the deleted-comments, it's interesting to note that $2^x$ and $3^x$ are log-convex, and the fact that sum of log-convex is log-convex. Now, you may look at the nice answers below to see how to prove the strictly convex.

Comment: @MartinR, isn't there a little extra work required to get *strict* convexity?

Comment: @MartinR, I think the interesting wrinkle here is that neither $2^x$ nor $3^x$ is strictly log convex, yet their sum is.

Comment: @BarryCipra: You are completely right. I'll delete my previous comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\alpha = \ln a$ and $\beta = \ln b$ we have
$$
 f(x) = \ln (e^{\alpha x} + e^{\beta x}) \, .
$$
Then
$$
 f'(x) = \frac{\alpha e^{\alpha x} + \beta e^{\beta x}}{e^{\alpha x} + e^{\beta x}}
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \frac{\alpha^2 e^{\alpha x} + \beta^2 e^{\beta x}}{e^{\alpha x} + e^{\beta x}} - \left( \frac{\alpha e^{\alpha x} + \beta e^{\beta x}}{e^{\alpha x} + e^{\beta x}} \right)^2 = \frac{(\alpha - \beta)^2 e^{(\alpha + \beta)x}}{(e^{\alpha x} + e^{\beta x})^2} > 0
$$

Comment: I like this answer. The function is simply the log-sum-exp function evaluated in an affine transformation of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor but perhaps helpful variant of Martin R's nice answer:

$$f(x)=\ln(e^{\alpha x}+e^{\beta x})=\ln e^{\alpha x}+\ln(1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x})=ax+\ln(1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x})$$

so

$$f'(x)=a+{(\beta-\alpha)e^{(\beta-\alpha)x}\over1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x}}=a+(\beta-\alpha)\left(1-{1\over1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x}} \right)=\beta-{\beta-\alpha\over1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x}}$$

and thus

$$f''(x)={(\beta-\alpha)^2e^{(\beta-\alpha)x}\over(1+e^{(\beta-\alpha)x})^2}\gt0$$

provided $\alpha\not=\beta$.

The only advantage here, if any, is that's a little easier to see how the key positive term $(\beta-\alpha)^2$ arises.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a clear reasoning!